# I can't figure out how to get into the else part of if (!isset($_get['id']) {code} else{code}

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I am making a foodmagazine as a project to help me get better at webdevelopment since i just started, but I got an index.php as a start.

```
<?php
//Require functions for actions
require_once "includes/actions.php";

//Based on the existence of the GET parameter, 1 of the 2 functions will be called
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $data = getDishes();
} else {
    $data = getDishDetails($_GET['id']);
}

//Set the header & output JSON so the client will know what to expect.
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

now i use the fetch to get to the getDishes

```
function loadFood(){
    fetch("webservice/index.php")
        .then(function(response){
            if(response.status === 200 && response.ok){
                return response.json();
            }
            console.log("oopsie");
        })
        .then(foodLoaded)
        .catch(foodNotLoaded);
}
```

then i load in the different types of food and make a div inside a grid this all works perfectly.

```
function foodLoaded(foods){
    divBody.innerHTML = "";
    for(let food of foods) {
        console.log(food);
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        divBody.appendChild(div);
        div.innerHTML = `<div id="food"> <h3>${food.name}</h3> <br> <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?${food.name}" style="width:300px;height:200px;" alt="${food.name}"> <form id="form" method="get"><input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="${food.id}"><button id="button" type="submit">Show recipe</button></form></div>`;
    }
}
```

but now i cant figure out how to make it so i get the else part of the index.php so i can add the dishDetails when i press the button.

Comment: You mean adding a parameter to the URL - `index.php?id=1` for example?

Comment: not really, that part works but i cant get the index.php to recognize a get has been set

Comment: It's literally what Nigel is telling you, add a parameter to your fetch url.

Comment: oh wait, thats probably it yeah. My bad and thanks!